# Get phone number of android device when connect wifi?

Tags: android, wifi

i make an application android to get phone number when the device connects to wifi in LAN network, but i cannot.
How can i get phone number of android device when connect to wifi?

Comment: Do you realize the security and privacy issues if you could do that?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot capture the phone number of a phone that connects to your wifi.

One way to do it is through a hotspot login page where you prompt for the mobile phone number to which you then send a one time password via SMS. The user is then able to proceed once he inputs the correct password he got through SMS.